# Parsing top logs data

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I m trying to parse a series of top logs collected. After parsing the original file, my current file is like this:

```
#TIMESTAMP 1524703273 : 04/25/2018 08:41:13 PM
Cpu(s): 33.9%us,  4.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 60.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.2%hi,  1.2%si,  0.0%st
#TIMESTAMP 1524703332 : 04/25/2018 08:42:12 PM
Cpu(s): 17.0%us,  2.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
#TIMESTAMP 1524703392 : 04/25/2018 08:43:12 PM
Cpu(s): 16.1%us,  2.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
```

I only want the "Epoch timestamp(2nd column (i.e) the field after #TIMESTAMP), followed by the %id in the next line to be in the same line", I want the parsed output to be like this(the timestamp and %id will always be in the alternative lines, i want it in the same line).

```
1524703273 60.2
1524703332 80.7
1524703392 80.8
```

Currently, I m using series of 'cut' command and using multiple output files to achieve this, is there a better way to achieve this in one attempt.

```
cut -d' ' -f 2,7 sample.txt > sample1.txt
cut -d' ' -f 2 sample1.txt > sample2.txt
cut -d'%' -f 1 sample2.txt > sample3.txt
```

And then `sed 'N;s/\n/ /' sample3.txt` to merge every two lines.

It would be good, if I can subtract the second value from 100 and have it in same file, if possible.

```
1524703273 39.8 --> (100-60.2)
1524703332 19.3 --> (100-80.7)
1524703392 19.2 --> (100-80.8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First problem

Try:

```
$ awk '/TIMESTAMP/{ts=$2; getline; print ts, $5+0}' logfile
1524703273 60.2
1524703332 80.7
1524703392 80.8
```

**How it works:**

- `/TIMESTAMP/{...}`

  This selects lines that contain `TIMESTAMP` and for those lines and only those lines, the commands in curly braces are executed.  Those commands are:
- `ts=$2`

  This saves the timestamp value in variable `ts`.
- `getline`

  This reads in the next line.
- `print ts, $5+0`

  This prints the timestamp value, `ts`, followed by the fifth column of the line we just read.  By adding zero to the value in the fifth column, we force awk to convert it to a number and that eliminates the unwanted characters `%id`.

#### Second problem

Taking your desired output literally:

```
$ awk '/TIMESTAMP/{ts=$2; getline; id=$5+0; printf "%s %s --> (100-%s)\n",ts,100-id,id}' logfile
1524703273 39.8 --> (100-60.2)
1524703332 19.3 --> (100-80.7)
1524703392 19.2 --> (100-80.8)
```

Or,maybe what you really wanted is:

```
$ awk '/TIMESTAMP/{ts=$2; getline; id=$5+0; print ts, id, 100-id}' logfile
1524703273 60.2 39.8
1524703332 80.7 19.3
1524703392 80.8 19.2
```

Or, maybe:

```
$ awk '/TIMESTAMP/{ts=$2; getline; id=$5+0; print ts, 100-id}' logfile
1524703273 39.8
1524703332 19.3
1524703392 19.2
```

Comment: That works like charm, thank you much, could you kindly explain.

Comment: @user9763248 Glad it works.  I just added an explanation.